# Sketch App Fills color dropdown solicitors

Tags: sketch-app, color-profile

I've been trying to figure this out today but had little success.  I'm wondering if any of you from the community could help me.

I'm trying to add the color pallet saved in my sketch design library to appear under the fill dropdown menu. Apple's iOS UI library (the one you get from their resources page) shows up automatically when the library is active, but mine doesn't.

Is there a way to show my color pallet (already saved as layer styles) from the master Sketch library into the Fill panel view? — Image attached

[image: Sample of where I would like my colors to show]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to do this with a vanilla Sketch, but it can be achieved with the help of Sketch-Palettes plugin : https://github.com/andrewfiorillo/sketch-palettes